# Static class can't use configuration Asp Net Core 2

Tags: c#, class, static

I have a class from an older project that builds all my html emails. I pass in a view model to that method that has all the appropriate items. Those view models are built from the class shown. I want to use DI now that I'm using Asp.Net Core 2

```
public static class EmailViewModel
{
    private static readonly string AppName = "Company Name";
    private static readonly IAppConfiguration _appConfig;

    public class AccountClosedEmailViewModel : IEmailViewModel
    {
        public AccountClosedEmailViewModel()
        {
            ApplicationName = AppName;
            EmailName = "Account Closed";
        }

        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string EmailName { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string RenewRegistrationUrl { get; set; }
    }
...rest removed for brevity
```

I want to use configuration from appsettings.json to bring in the values required from this class instead of setting them at the top of the class as private fields.

```
//don't want to do this
private static readonly string AppName = "Company Name";
//want to do this
private readonly IAppConfiguration _appConfig;

//and in the code use _appConfig.AppName
```

But because this is a static class, I can't have a constructor with a parameter to bring in the configuration. I am not a professional programmer so this issue has always stumped me. How do I get this to work? I've spent an inordinate amount of time trying various changes but still can't get it right.

Update per NightOwl888's suggestions:

I wrote a new class

```
 public class EmailModel : IEmailModel
{
    private static IAppConfiguration _appConfig;
    private static IAzureConfiguration _azureConfig;

    public string TemplateHtml { get; set; }

    public EmailModel(IAppConfiguration config, IAzureConfiguration azureConfig)
    {
        _appConfig = config;
        _azureConfig = azureConfig;
        TemplateHtml = TemplateHtmlFromMaster();
    }

    public string TemplateHtmlFromMaster()
    {
        var filepath = Path.Combine(_azureConfig.AzureBaseBlob, _azureConfig.AzureEmailTemplatePath,
            "EmailMaster.html");
        return File.ReadAllText(filepath)
            .Replace("{year}", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()
                .Replace("{applicationname)", _appConfig.AppName));
    }

    public class AccountClosedEmailViewModel : IEmailViewModel
    {
        public AccountClosedEmailViewModel()
        {
            ApplicationName = _appConfig.AppName;
            EmailName = "Account Closed";
        }

        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string EmailName { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string RenewRegistrationUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I registered it in Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IEmailModel, EmailModel>();
```

But when I try to use it elsewhere

```
var em = new EmailModel();
```

It errs, and intellisense is showing that I need to pass in the two expected parameters. To be clear, this code is in the Services project in the solution (Class Library Asp.Net Core 2) and NOT in the Asp.Net Web Application project.

Any help in getting me to both understand how this works and to get it to work, is most appreciated.

Comment: The problem is having the viewmodel class as static. You'll probably run into other problems because of that decision. You should make it an instanciable class and pass the configs in the constructor.

Comment: You can have static constructor, but of course, without parameters. When you want a initialized parameter by another part of code *(determined by some different means, e.g. command line parameters)*, you need to make a 'single set **static** property' *(manual code)*, or make the class non-static.

Comment: Make it non-static and register in asp.net core DI container as singleton, so it will have the same semantics (one instance for all consumers).

Comment: The problem is if I make it a non-static class, it breaks a lot of other code which Re-sharper is telling me requires it to be static so its methods are available elsewhere. I could forgo the constructor, and write an Init method for the class, but I don't know how to get the app configuration working in that Init method.

Comment: @Phil-R...I don't disagree, but then I have to also have that configuration available everywhere I new that class up from as I have to pass it as a parameter

Comment: Also, from MSDN docs "a static class can make your implementation simpler and faster because you do not have to create an object in order to call its methods." and that is all this class does, have methods for building emails.

Comment: *a static class can make your implementation simpler and faster because you do not have to create an object in order to call its methods.* - What that means is the static class instance is created the first time it is called and reused each additional time it is called. This is *exactly* the same behavior as if you were to register as singleton `services.AddSingleton<INonStaticService, NonStaticService>()`. However, with statics you have to jump through hoops to supply dependencies. With instance constructors, you can readily inject them and swap them for any number of reasons.

Comment: *I have to also have that configuration available everywhere I new that class up from as I have to pass it as a parameter* - No, the DI container will pass the parameter, you only need to register the dependencies with the DI container and get rid of the statics.

Comment: @NightOwl888...thanks for the comments. Please see my update in the OP.

Comment: Since you want to use DI for `EmailModel`, you should not create its instances with `new` operator. You should just inject `IEmailModel` into classes that want to use it. Inject here means that you add it as constructor parameter in consuming classes.